# Adding a new line to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, console, newline, jscrollpane

I'm creating a console and would like to know how I can set my console output, a JScrollPane to add multiple lines of text, similar to map.addText, map being the name, yet without adding the charactor number. Instead I want to set the text to be put in the following line so say the console output is like this:

```
The time is...
Random Text
```

With the addText code it would only do this:

```
The time is...Random Text
```

Not pretty. Of course there is setText, yet that only replaces the contents.

Edit #1: user3152069 was correct in saying map.append would work.

Comment: How about inserting a line break character, `\n` in there?

Comment: How about using setText(getText() + ...); ? New line characters are "\n" btw. I also believe there is a methode appendText().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add "lines" to a JScrollPane, nor should you want to. Instead you add lines to whatever component the JScrollPane holds, a very important component, and something you never tell us about, but probably should.

So take your pick. If it's a JList, then add a new line to the JList's model via the `addElement(...)` method. If the JScrollPane displays a JTextArea, then append a String to the JTextArea via its `append(...)` method, but making sure that it contains the `\n` new line String.

---

Note, I'm not sure what you mean by

> similar to map.addText

What is "map"? What is "addText"? Is it a method? If so, it's not a method I'm familiar with.

Comment: Map is the scroll pane's name. "addText" supposedly used to be in the swing layout. it would look like this: *.addText(charNumber, string);

Comment: also, the person user3152069 was correct. that is the way.

Comment: @GraniteBear: I am confused beyond measure. JScrollPane does not have an `addText(...)` method.

Comment: I am slightly confused too, it used to show up in eclipse, nevertheless, the append method seemed to work for me while also using \n. addText or whatever was no help for me.

Comment: @GraniteBear: Please strive to be accurate and precise when asking questions here. `addText(...)` is not the same as `setText(...)`. Also, if you can call `setText(...)` on a component, then it is not the JScrollPane but rather some component that it is holding. You can't be sloppy when coding because the compiler is unforgiving. Same for when asking questions here.

Comment: I went back and found that the JScrollPane is redirected to the name "map": 
        map.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 204, 0));
        map.setColumns(20);
        map.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 0, 13)); 
        map.setRows(5);
        **jScrollPane1.setViewportView(map);**

in other words, map.setText(""); is direct to the pane, rather than an internal component.

I also located it: javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(String t)
set text is a universal java way of setting how a button, field etc. looks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    map.addText("The time is...\n");
    map.addText("Random Text");
```